# __ticket_spinlock high cpu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-10.04, io, linux-kernel

We are having a strange problem on our Ubuntu 10.04 KVM infrastructure, where periodically, one of two vm webservers freaks out, with persistently high load, even if we restart the applications. (the only thing using any significant system resources inside the vm) If we stop the webserver daemon fully, load does drop, but it jumps back up to a high level when we start it up again. A reboot of the vm guest clears the problem, and it will run fine for several days before the problem returns.

Recently, we installed "perf" on the hypervisor and noticed that during the high load period, the kernel function "__ticket_spinlock" is using a large percentage (30-60%) of CPU, compared to less than 1% during normal operation. Reboot of the vm with the high load clears this up. Doing some research into understanding spinlocks and ticket spinlocks, we've come up with the hypothesis that the vm experiencing high load is waiting for a lock held by some other vm, and for some reason not getting it.

We discovered a difference (among many) between the hypervisors that have this problem, and CentOS ones from a prior deployment that are configured similarly, but don't. The kernel for the Ubuntu 10.04 hypervisor is compiled using a different default IOScheduler (deadline) and preempt_voluntary is off. We've synced these configs between the two sites, and are waiting to see if the vm on the updated hypervisor freaks out again.

> ** Edit:
>   We were never able to find the root cause, but since the migration to 
>   Ubuntu 14.04, we have not seen the problem again.

Is there any way to detect what device a Linux process is waiting for, when it's in a spinlock/ticket spinlock? Is there any way to detect what Linux process has a lock on a particular device?

Comment: you are on an old and known buggy version of Ubuntu, using KVM, which is known to work much better on Fedora/RHEL. Why do you insist on staying there and fighting bugs when you can switch to a normal distribution?

Comment: "Old" and "known buggy" aren't particularly helpful descriptions of the situation, and don't lead anyone to an actual known bug that would drive someone to a new version or a new distro. Dropping my ambiguous question #1 because it invites flame bait like this.

Comment: Well, I've been working with KVM issues since 2008 on a daily basis, and ubuntu 8-10 was particularly horrible, the amount of bugs was incredible, especially when none of them could be reproduced under RHEL. It is still way behind RHEL and Fedora in terms of stability as a hypervisor, and no wonder - all the work in the area (kvm/qemu/libvirt/lvm/dm-multipath/cgroups/etc) is being done primarily at RHT and tested under Fedora and then RHEL.